# Adding a Button Click Sound Unity3D 5.4

Tags: button, audio, unity-game-engine, onclick

I have been trying to add a button click sound to a button in my Unity3D game. However, everything II have tried (see below) does not produce the desired effect (a sound on click.) The button works but does not produce a sound. The following links contain things that I have tried and my latest attempt in scripting is attached as well. The audio is setup to play from the inspector (per the last link) which is why there is no `audioSource.play()` in the script itself. I want the sound to play when the button is clicked:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/26241/play-sound-when-gui-button-is-pressed.html
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/182754/play-sound-on-button-press.html
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/857810/play-audio-from-46-ui-button-on-click-script.html

```
private AudioSource audioSource;
private float audioTimer;
public void LoadLevel(string name)
{
    StartCoroutine(AudioLength(audioTimer));
    SceneManager.LoadScene(name);
}
public void Next(string name)
{
    StartCoroutine(AudioLength(audioTimer));
    SceneManager.LoadScene(name);
}

void Start()
{
    audioSource = this.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    audioTimer = audioSource.clip.length;
}

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Start Menu");
    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}   

IEnumerator AudioLength(float audioTimer)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(audioTimer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the answer with the help of two folks over at community.gamedev.tv.

First, the issue was caused by the scene changing before the audio had a chance to play. Secondly, I had to add my `LoadScene`to my Coroutine in order to get it to process the delay and then load the next scene. I also had to pass the `name`variable as a string through my coroutine.